# GFS2 flags 0x00000005 blocked,join

Tags: lvm, gfs

I have cluster RHEL6, 
cman, corosync, pacemaker.

After adding new memebers I got error in GFS mounting. GFS never mounts on servers.

```
group_tool
fence domain
member count  4
victim count  0
victim now    0
master nodeid 1
wait state    none
members       1 2 3 4

dlm lockspaces
name          clvmd
id            0x4104eefa
flags         0x00000000
change        member 4 joined 1 remove 0 failed 0 seq 1,1
members       1 2 3 4

gfs mountgroups
name          lv_gfs_01
id            0xd5eacc83
flags         0x00000005 blocked,join
change        member 3 joined 1 remove 0 failed 0 seq 1,1
members       1 2 3
```

In processes:

```
root      2695  2690  0 08:03 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/gfs2 start
root      2702  2695  0 08:03 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/init.d/gfs2 start
root      2704  2703  0 08:03 pts/1    00:00:00 /sbin/mount.gfs2 /dev/mapper/vg_shared-lv_gfs_01 /mnt/share -o rw,_netdev,noatime,nodiratime
```

fsck.gfs2 -yf /dev/vg_shared/lv_gfs_01

```
Initializing fsck
jid=1: Replayed 0 of 0 journaled data blocks
jid=1: Replayed 20 of 21 metadata blocks
Recovering journals (this may take a while)

Journal recovery complete.
Validating Resource Group index.
Level 1 rgrp check: Checking if all rgrp and rindex values are good.
(level 1 passed)
RGs: Consistent: 183   Cleaned: 1   Inconsistent: 0   Fixed: 0   Total: 184
2 blocks may need to be freed in pass 5 due to the cleaned resource groups.
Starting pass1
Pass1 complete
Starting pass1b
Pass1b complete
Starting pass1c
Pass1c complete
Starting pass2
Pass2 complete
Starting pass3
Pass3 complete
Starting pass4
Pass4 complete
Starting pass5
Block 11337799 (0xad0047) bitmap says 1 (Data) but FSCK saw 0 (Free)
Fixed.
Block 11337801 (0xad0049) bitmap says 1 (Data) but FSCK saw 0 (Free)
Fixed.
RG #11337739 (0xad000b) free count inconsistent: is 65500 should be 65502
RG #11337739 (0xad000b) Inode count inconsistent: is 15 should be 13
Resource group counts updated
Pass5 complete
The statfs file is wrong:

Current statfs values:
blocks:  12057320 (0xb7fae8)
free:    9999428 (0x989444)
dinodes: 15670 (0x3d36)

Calculated statfs values:
blocks:  12057320 (0xb7fae8)
free:    9999432 (0x989448)
dinodes: 15668 (0x3d34)
The statfs file was fixed.
Writing changes to disk
gfs2_fsck complete
```

gfs2_edit -p 0xad0047 field di_size /dev/vg_shared/lv_gfs_01

```
10 (Block 11337799 is type 10: Ext. attrib which is not implemented)
```

Howto drop flag blocked,join from GFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by reboot all servers which have GFS, 
it is one of the unpleasant behavior of GFS.

GFS lock based on kernel and in the few cases it solved only with reboot.

there is very usefull manual - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Global_File_System_2/index.html